# how to hide the Grid using button click event in silverlight mvvm?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

In my project (Silverlight5 with MVVM), i need to hide the Grid using button click event. here the button also located in the grid. Is there anyway to hide this grid..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewmodel should contain property (for example, `IsGridVisible`):

```
public bool IsGridVisible
{
   get {return _isGridVisible;}
   set {
          _isGridVisible = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("IsGridVisible");
       }
}
```

Then, you can bind `Grid.Visibility` to your `IsGridVisible` property, thought `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

And then, you can simply switch state in your button`s command handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visibility property of the grid.

```
grid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: this answer is not a solution for his problem using mvvm,he should use a property in the viewmodel as described in the second answer;     and good luck